# How to identify N last unique cells?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have in the dataframe a column `ID` (all ID's captured by the movement of people). I created a new column using `collect_list` to get all the ID's as a list. How to get the N=5 last elements of the created array?

I managed to solve the problem using an UDF but the performance is not great and I needed to split the dataframe into many chunks. Is it possible to improve performance using some Spark function or other technique?

```
index;collect_list;window
0;[F];[F]
1;[F, B];[B, F]
2;[F, B, A];[A, B, F]
3;[F, B, A, F];[A, B, F]
4;[F, B, A, F, B];[A, B, F]
5;[F, B, A, F, B, G];[A, B, F, G]
6;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E];[A, B, E, F, G]
7;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F];[A, B, E, F, G]
8;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E];[A, B, E, F, G]
9;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B];[A, B, E, F, G]
10;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A];[A, B, E, F, G]
11;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D];[A, B, D, E, F]
12;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F];[A, B, D, E, F]
13;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E];[A, B, D, E, F]
14;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E, E];[A, B, D, E, F]
15;[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E, E, D];[A, B, D, E, F]
```

[image]

This is the function I used in Python for Pandas and Spark :

```
def getLast(arr, n=5):
    
    addedSet = set()
    
    result = []
    
    lenArr = len(arr)

    
    for i in range(lenArr):
    
        element = arr[lenArr-i-1]
        
        if element not in addedSet:
            
            result.append(element)
            addedSet.add(element)
        
            if len(addedSet) == 5 : break
        
    return sorted(result)
```

I also wrote the function in Scala to improve performance, but it crashes with `Out Of Memory Error`:

```
  def list_array_V(myArray: Array[String], n: Int = 5): Array[String] = {

    @tailrec
    def window(myArray: Array[String], currentSet: Set[String] = Set()): Array[String] = {

      if (currentSet.size >= n) currentSet.toArray
      else window(myArray.slice(0, myArray.length - 1), myArray.takeRight(1).toSet ++ currentSet)

    }

    window(myArray)

  }
```

My Spark version is 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this udf solution:

```
val df = spark.sql(""" with t1( 
select array("F") as x  union all
select array("F,B") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E,B") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E,B,A") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E,B,A,D") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E,B,A,D,F") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E,B,A,D,F,E") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E,B,A,D,F,E,E") as x  union all
select array("F,B,A,F,B,G,E,F,E,B,A,D,F,E,E,D") as x  
) 
select x as arr from t1
""")


def last_5(arr :Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
      val x1=scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
      arr.reverse.map( x => if(x1.size < 5 ) x1.add(x) )
      x1.toSeq
    }

val udf_last_5 = udf( last_5(_:Seq[String]) )

df.withColumn("result",udf_last_5(col("arr"))).show(false)

+------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|arr                                             |result         |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|[F]                                             |[F]            |
|[F, B]                                          |[B, F]         |
|[F, B, A]                                       |[B, F, A]      |
|[F, B, A, F]                                    |[B, F, A]      |
|[F, B, A, F, B]                                 |[B, F, A]      |
|[F, B, A, F, B, G]                              |[B, F, G, A]   |
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E]                           |[B, F, G, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F]                        |[B, F, G, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E]                     |[B, F, G, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B]                  |[B, F, G, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A]               |[B, F, G, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D]            |[B, F, D, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F]         |[B, F, D, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E]      |[B, F, D, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E, E]   |[B, F, D, E, A]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E, E, D]|[B, F, D, E, A]|
+------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

For getting the sorted result, you can use `x1.toSeq.sorted` in the udf()

**Update2:**

Inside the udf, the loop can be exited early by using scala utils breakable.

```
def last_5(arr :Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    import scala.util.control.Breaks._
    val x1=scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
    breakable { 
        for ( x <- arr.reverse )
        { 
            if(x1.size == 5 )
            {
                break
            }   
            x1.add(x)
        }
    }
    x1.toSeq
}

val udf_last_5 = udf( last_5(_:Seq[String]) )

df.withColumn("result",udf_last_5(col("arr"))).show(false)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why is it more rapid than my scala function ?

Comment: as soon as we get the last five unique items, the array traversal is stopped. We are using break and exiting the for loop. In other solutions, we are iterating till the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code? No UDF needed ;)

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'seq',
    F.sequence(F.lit(0),F.size('collect_list') - 1)
).select('*',
    F.array_sort(
        F.arrays_zip(
            F.map_values(F.map_from_arrays('collect_list', 'seq')),
            F.map_keys(F.map_from_arrays('collect_list', 'seq'))
        )
    ).alias('list')
).select('*',
    F.when(
        F.size('list') >= 5, 
        F.slice('list',-5,5)
    ).otherwise(
        F.col('list')
    ).alias('list2')
).select('*',
    F.expr('transform(list2, x -> x["1"]) as window')
).select(
    'collect_list',
    F.array_sort('window').alias('window')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|collect_list                                    |window         |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|[F]                                             |[F]            |
|[F, B]                                          |[B, F]         |
|[F, B, A]                                       |[A, B, F]      |
|[F, B, A, F]                                    |[A, B, F]      |
|[F, B, A, F, B]                                 |[A, B, F]      |
|[F, B, A, F, B, G]                              |[A, B, F, G]   |
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E]                           |[A, B, E, F, G]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F]                        |[A, B, E, F, G]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E]                     |[A, B, E, F, G]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B]                  |[A, B, E, F, G]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A]               |[A, B, E, F, G]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D]            |[A, B, D, E, F]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F]         |[A, B, D, E, F]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E]      |[A, B, D, E, F]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E, E]   |[A, B, D, E, F]|
|[F, B, A, F, B, G, E, F, E, B, A, D, F, E, E, D]|[A, B, D, E, F]|
+------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: yes sorry, please do `spark.sql('set spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy = LAST_WIN')`